# Boardgame-Map with crossroads etc

Tags: delphi, logic

I have a little logical problem over here.

As the title says, I try to build a boardgame as a computer-program (maybe with internet-support, but thats another story)

As for now, I have a map, which has some crossroads in it, hence I cannot simply define the fields as '1, 2, 3, 4, ...' because if there is a crossroad at field 10, I would have more than one field which has to be labeled 11 (Because then there is a field left and right of field 10, for example.)

So the problem is, if I cannot define the Board in numbers then I cannot simply get the possible positions a player can take when he rolls 2d6-dices with calculating 'Field-Nr. + RandomRange(1,6) + RandomRange(1,6)'

Does anybody have an idea, how to define a Map like this on another way, where I still can calculate the possible new-fields for Player X with a 2d6-dice-roll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is a *board*? which component do you use to build it? BTW, I'll **inherit** from the component you use for each coordinate, and I'll add it a **custom property** to store the allowed directions... then, I'll access this property and not its *name*...

Comment: Is the board game carcassone by any chance? Anyway, you explanation is not enough. We can't tell what you mean from this. Well, I can't. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: sorry i wrote this in comment as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Instead* of dynamic arrays, I would recommend using a **linked-list** of **records** to describe the surrounding cells, and traverse the player's location and possible moves using that linked-list.

First, define a record that describes each cell in your board's playable grid (the cells on the grid can be four-sided like a chessboard, or hexagonal like in Civilization V) ... each cell record should contain info such as coordinates, which players are *also* in that cell, any rewards/hazards/etc that would affect gameplay, etc. (you get the idea).

Finally, the linked-list joins *all* of these cells, effectively pointing to any connected cells.  That way, all you'd need is the cell location of Player X and calculate possible moves over *n* amount of cells (determined by the dice roll), traversing the adjoining cells (that don't have hazards, for example).

If all you want is to track the possible roads, you can also use this approach to identify possible paths (instead of cells) Player X can travel on.

Comment: Okay, now I understand, what my friend tried to tell me earlier :D Thank you very much, that helped a lot.

Comment: Glad to help ... don't forget to select one of the answers provided as your accepted answer, so you can increase your reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand well... (i don't thing so) this might help you. Just use dynamic arrays for your boardgame field and change your actions after the dimensions x,y .... Look at this "type Name = array of {array of ...} Base type; // Dynamic array"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a graph of connected vertices. When a player is at a particular vertex of N edges, assuming N < 12, the new Field will be reached from traversing edge number N % ( rand(6) + rand(6) ).

You could also just do rand(12), but that would have an even distribution, unlike 2d6.